# How to split org-roam-capture-templates in to multiple lines?

Tags: org-mode, string, org-roam, template, style

I have following config for my org-roam:

```elisp
(use-package org-roam
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq org-roam-v2-ack t)
  :custom
  (org-roam-directory "~/roamnotes")
  (org-roam-completion-everywhere t)
  
  (org-roam-capture-templates
   '(("d" "Default" plain
      "%?"
      :if-new (file+head
               "%<%Y%m%d%H%M%S>-${slug}.org" 
               "#+title: ${title}\n#+filetags: :nohtmlexport:\n#+date: %U\n#+auto_tangle: nil") ;; I want to split this long line
      :unnarrowed t)
     ))
  :config
  (org-roam-setup)
  (require 'org-roam-dailies)
  (org-roam-db-autosync-mode)
  )
```

**What I want to do**: To split long line: `"#+title: ${title}\n#+filetags: :nohtmlexport:\n#+date: %U\n#+auto_tangle: nil"`.

---

**What I've tried so far I:** This works without an error, but stylistically looks very bad. (Just bad indent)

```elisp
  ...
  ...
  (org-roam-capture-templates
   '(("d" "Default" plain
      "%?"
      :if-new (file+head
               "%<%Y%m%d%H%M%S>-${slug}.org"
               "#+title: ${title}
#+filetags: :nohtmlexport:
#+date: %U
#+auto_tangle: nil")
      :unnarrowed t)
     ))
  ...
  ...
  )
```

**What I've tried so far II:** This stylistically desirable, but this gets an error:

```elisp
  (org-roam-capture-templates
   '(("d" "Default" plain
      "%?"
      :if-new (file+head
               "%<%Y%m%d%H%M%S>-${slug}.org"
               (concat
                "#+title: ${title}\n"
                "#+filetags: :nohtmlexport:\n"
                "#+date: %U\n"
                "#+auto_tangle: nil"
                )
               )
      :unnarrowed t)
     ))
```

```
org-roam-capture--fill-template: Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, (concat "#+title: ${title}
" "#+filetags: :nohtmlexport:
" "#+date: %U
" "#+auto_tangle: nil")
```

---

**Question:**

- Why I can't use `concat` inside `org-roam-capture-templates` as written in above?
- If it's possible to use `concat` (or anything else), how to implement it?

Comment: This is a (frequent) duplicate and the answer is: Use `backquote` and `comma` to evaluate part of the (now completely unevaluated because it is quoted) expression.

Comment: Did you mean `\`(file+head "...org" ,(concat "line1\n" "line2\n" "line3\n"))` ? Am I doing correct? This produces error `org-roam-capture--prepare-buffer: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil`

Comment: No, actually: the backquote should replace the quote in front of the whole list. The comma is correctly placed. The quote says: don't evaluate anything in the following expression; the backquote says: don't evaluate anything in the following expression except evaluate any expression that is preceded by a comma. There is an additional "advanced" wrinkle with `,@` which you can read about in the Emacs Lisp Ref doc.

Comment: Could you tell me where should I put backquote? I still couldn't manage it to put correct place, I've tried many possible to positions

Comment: Just replace the quote: `...'(("d" "Default" plain ...` with a backquote: ``...`(("d" "Default" plain ...``.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh thanks